# How to tell if dates are sequential or not excluding weekends

Tags: c#

I have a method that will return true/false if a list of dates is sequential or not. I need to exclude weekends, so if the list is Thu 5, Fri 6, Mon 9 Tue 10 then its true (sequential).

My method is -

```
public static bool IsSequential(List<DateTime> timeList)
{
    //populate list..
    return timeList.Zip(timeList.Skip(1),
                                     (a, b) => b.Date == a.Date.AddDays(1))
                                .All(x => x);
}
```

Comment: So... what did you try? Where are you stuck?

Comment: what if the data set is `Thu 5, Fri 6, Sa 7, Mon 9, Tue 10` - so with `Sa 7` does `So 8` need to be present to be valid?

Comment: @RandRandom Sat and Sun will never be in the data set.

Comment: this would be better with a standard loop, not using linq

Comment: Do you need to exclude holidays too? Or just weekends?

Comment: Try : return timeList.Take(timeList.Count() - 1).Select((x, i) => x <= timeList[i + 1]).All(x => x);

Comment: @Radovancev I dont need to exclude holidays

Comment: The logic is not at all complicated if you write a simple loop, starting at the beginning, keeping track of where you are and skipping weekend days. There's undoubtedly a pointed LINQ one-liner as well, but it's not going to be more readable, or faster.

Comment: @dynmatt Then just use DayOfWeek, thats System enum, Saturday =6, Sunday =0 and exclude that days from list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

Just check the days and compare it with an element of the list.

```
public static bool IsSequential(List<DateTime> timeList)
{
    // less than 2? it's sequential.
    if (timeList.Count < 2)
        return true;

    // an array of valid DayOfWeek's
    var validDays = new DayOfWeek[] { DayOfWeek.Monday, DayOfWeek.Tuesday, DayOfWeek.Wednesday, DayOfWeek.Thursday, DayOfWeek.Friday };

    // the first date to start with
    var startDate = timeList.First();

    // index of the source list
    int i = 0;
    // an offset from the startDate
    int dayCounter = 0;

    // loop until all timeList items are compared.
    while (i < timeList.Count)
    {
        // get the next date to check.
        var newDate = startDate.AddDays(dayCounter);

        // check if it needs to be present in the timeList
        if (validDays.Contains(newDate.DayOfWeek))
        {
            // if they are not equal, there is a gap.
            if (timeList[i] != newDate)
                return false;

            // increase the index for the next item. (only on a valid DayOfWeek)
            i++;
        }
        // increase the offset from the startDate
        dayCounter++;
    }
    // all are equal.
    return true;
}
```

It would be possible with difficult linq queries, but I think this is more easy to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Just `AddDays` based on the `DayOfWeek`, so if `Monday` add 3 days if not only add 1.

So instead of only `a.Date.AddDays(1)`

Extend it to this:

`a.Date.AddDays((b.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday ? 3 : 1))`

```
public static bool IsSequential(List<DateTime> timeList)
{
    //populate list..
    return timeList.Zip(timeList.Skip(1),(a, b) => b.Date == a.Date.AddDays((b.Date.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Monday ? 3 : 1))).All(x => x);
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/CtRk6K

Comment: But I do like this one...